# How to center icon by horizontal parent block?

Tags: html, css

I have the following block:

```
<div class="class-journal-mobile-navigation-move left">
<i class="material-icons"> arrow_back_ios</i>
</div>

.class-journal-mobile-navigation-move {
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #3e4eb8;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: table;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.class-journal-mobile-navigation-move i {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #3e4eb8;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I need to center `i` element by center in parent block, now it look as:

[image]

After applying changes it looks now as:

[image]

Comment: As you can see left arrow is not centered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flexbox:

instead of display: table; for class-journal-mobile-navigation-move,

```css
h1, p {
  font-family: Lato;
}

.class-journal-mobile-navigation-move {
      border-radius: 50%;
      border: 1px solid #3e4eb8;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      /* display: table; */
      cursor: pointer;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;

      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
  }

  .class-journal-mobile-navigation-move i {
      font-size: 24px;
      color: #3e4eb8;
      /* display: table-cell; */
      text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
  <div class="class-journal-mobile-navigation-move left">
  <i class="material-icons"><</i>
  </div>
```

Comment: The same result, I think problem is in width of `i`

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines:

```
.class-journal-mobile-navigation-move {
   display: flex;
   align-items:center;
   justify-content:center;
}
```